# Protecting certain files and folders from view within a public folder

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

Today I've been struggling with this for a while.
What I am trying to accomplish is that I need to block all users from acessing a certain php files and images and more things (they are in a separate folder).

I am using WAMP-server.

I do not want the users to be able to go to just that site, like "www/images/crazy-cat-picture.jpg" (or more like "www/phpScripts/sign-up-user.php")
but I still want the users ta be able to see the pictures on my website and call the php scripts.

**I tried 3 different ways, and none have been working good.**

**1:** Place the folder outside of the www directory

This did not work since the php and html pages can not find the data and it will simply not display it.

**2:** .htaccess file, where I wrote this:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168
```

This did not work since it's blocking the acess completely, and the users can not view the content even if they are on a seperate website.

**3:** .htaccess file, where i wrote this:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

This will remove the standard, and instead of displaying the folder it will place the user to index.php, I then have made this file re-directing to the error 403 page, this works pretty good.
But the problem here is that users can still access the data if they have the whole path, like "www/images/crazy-cat-picture.jpg"

Then I have been thinking about creating complicated names on all my php script files and the pictures that the users upload, this will make it very hard to be able to find the images and files. But I wonder if there is not a better way of doing this, like block all the content in a specific folder if the users are not calling it from one of my websites.

**The question is: Do someone know how I can make it impossible to find content in a folder but still make users able to use it on my website?**

Sorry for making this to a long post, but I hope there are someone who can answer my question.
Thank you!

Comment: For php files you can create empty index.html file in each folder.but for images you can not do anything since all images which available in your site were downloaded by client.

Comment: There are a few ways, easiest way is to check referrer is set, but some users set there browser to not populate referrer. Another is to use php to load the file, you can then do things like set CSRF tokens on the page that loads the image, another way is to use cookies ect, but in the end **its all futile** because if someone wants it then there is nothing stopping them apart from you not actually **publicly** display the image in the first place. Its the same for any resource, images,videos,music its all accessible else the browser would not be able to download it and display it. good luck

Comment: Are you trying to protect a folder or a certain files?

Comment: @user3810556 Check my answer and let me know if it worked for you, since I'm not sure how Apache acts on Windows :)

Comment: @LozCheroneツ
Thanks for the answers everyone, now I understand that you have to be able to access the files seperatly if you would be able to access them through the website. I guess I don't need to protect them from users visiting them individually anyways, since everyone can acess them from the website anyways, then I'll just code the restrictions into the files, and that images can always be acessed in some way if they are loaded into your site.
Thanks for the fast answers :)

Comment: @hex494D49 No sorry, I need 15 rep to upvote, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Protecting only certain files and folders**

`1st solution`

Next example shows how to protect two .php files, two folders and two .jpg images. Everything else should remain accessible.

`Create an .htaccess file` and place it within the folder there the protected assets are

```
# .htaccess
<FilesMatch ^((001|002)\.php$|folder-001|folder-002|(image-001|image-002)\.jpg)$>
    AuthUserFile /absolute-path-to-the-password-file/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Private Area"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Then create an encrypted password - use this site [htpasswd generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator)

`Create an .htpasswd` and place it outside of your public_html folder. It contains an username and password generated from the service mentioned above.

```
# .htpasswd
username:j9mKJ6TCrsbSk
```

As you can see, the files above will be password protected

`2nd solution`

You may use the next solution as well

```
# .htaccess
<FilesMatch ^((001|002)\.php$|folder-001|folder-002|(image-001|image-002)\.jpg)$>
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This solution doesn't need the .htpasswd part but files listed in `FilesMatch` directive will be inaccessible for anyone.

---

Tested on Debian 7 / Apache 2