# Laravel, protecting a folder in public folder

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a folder inside the public folder in Laravel app, this folder is called 'docs' and I want to protect it from unauthorised access. So basically when a user tries to access this folder they should get redirected to the login page. I tried doing this:

```
Route::get('\docs','DocsController@protected')->middleware('auth');
```

But Laravel doesn't even get triggered and the user goes directly to the folder.

Comment: You can revoke access by `.htaccess` also

Comment: @marmahan It's because you have protected the routes only. Although the route name and the public folder name are the same, however, I don't think it will protect you. Then the only way I can think of to protect it from unauthorized access via `.htaccess` that @TalhaF. suggested already.

Comment: Ok. thanks. How should I protect this folder in the .htaccess?

Comment: @marmahan Check the following link to get the idea-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716823/protecting-certain-files-and-folders-from-view-within-a-public-folder

Comment: Thank you. I think i'll go with changing my folder location and then accessing it using Laravel filesystem abstraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess file to protect this folder. But IMHO the better way is to move this folder from public, and access the docs using php code (using something like thephpleague/flysystem).

Comment: the flysystem requires php >= 5.5.9. So yes. Sorry I forget that laravel uses it's own [filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem) abstraction. So you dont need to use flysystem.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested the solution with filesystem and it works fine